# Querying a dynamic JSON KeyValue Store and pivoting it in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database-design, pivot-table

I have a query in Microsoft SQL Server querying a JSON Column

```
SELECT [KEY], [Value]
FROM openjson((SELECT TOP 1 KeyValueIntegers from 
[MatrixAnalyzer].[CountsMatrixInitial] Where MatrixId = 16), '$') AS L1

//returns
KEY          VALUE

WT1          [1,2,3,4,5]
LDI_FC       [5,4,3,2,1]
```

both the names of the keys and the number of the keys are unknown. I am trying to pivot this so that I get a matrix that looks like.

```
WT1       LDI_FC 
1         5
2         4
3         3
4         2
5         1
```

What is the most efficient way to pivot this table. If I knew the names of the key's before hand it wouldn't be so bad but they are always different. How would I go about doing a dynamic pivot.

Comment: Why are you using `TOP 1`? This is undeterministic without an `ORDER BY` if `[MatrixAnalyzer].[CountsMatrixInitial]` has more than one row

Comment: Also your expected results don't seem to correlate with the input data https://dbfiddle.uk/DHHm4MaY

Comment: This is just dummy data that I made up, The Idea is that LT1 and LDI_FC could be called anything, it could be LT3 and LDI4K.

The lists of Integers are also equally random.

Comment: the dbfiddle example got me close. I was able to ask ChatGPT with this exact input, the answer involved putting my select statement into a list variable and then using a dynamic sql statement involving the cross apply operator to get the answer.
Flagged the comment about the question not providing a minimal reproducible example as it does. It specificies Microsoft SQL Server and gives both the SQL statement, the existing table, and the resulting table desired. The fact that I am using openJSON implies a modern version of SQL Server. so DDL or Insert Statements would add unecessary complexity